# drupal site better performance

Tags: database, performance, drupal

i'm working on drupal community site and i want to ask about this things :

1 - how to hide the drupal information from my site ?

2 - how to make the drupal site more secure ?

3 - how to make my site work as fast as possible when there is a lot of visitors and users on the site

and there is a lot of interaction with the database at the same time?

4 - how to configure drupal to work with high server load and how to configure my server's hardware to work with high load ?

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1 - how to hide the drupal information
>   from my site ?

What information? You can show/hide anything in your theme implementation

> 2 - how to make the drupal site more
>   secure ?

Stay up to date.

> 3 - how to make my site work as fast
>   as possible when there is a lot of
>   visitors and users on the site and
>   there is a lot of interaction with the
>   database at the same time?
>
> 4 - how to configure drupal to work
>   with high server load and how to
>   configure my server's hardware to work
>   with high load ?

Start with the [pantheon project](http://groups.drupal.org/pantheon) use it and learn from it:

Pressflow (a performance tuned version of Drupal)
Varnish Reverse Proxy Cache for anonymous users
APC for OpCode Caching
Memcached for easing the load on the DB

Use as few modules as possible.

The first area to need help in a social setup (lotsa logged in users posting content) is likely going to be the DB and so learning how to use Memcached will go a long way to helping you scale at the start

For further reading on Drupal Performance you might want to read everything from 2bits:

http://2bits.com/contents/articles

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand this question? Do you mean a clustered DB? Or splitting certain items across separate DB's?

Comment: thank you but what about making the site works with 2 or more databases? i read that it will make the db faster

Comment: hmm, I don't think you want to go down that road just yet. I'd keep things as simple as possible, if need be, I would separate Varnish, Apache, MySQL & Memcached onto separate servers/VM's and then you'll be able to scale the necessary item (DB say) horizontally & vertically as needed. As far as DB replication & clustering, maybe, but I wouldn't worry about that to start unless you are launching with a huge user/content base (like migrating a large community from something else)

Comment: ok thank you very much i will need sometime to review your suggestions so any additional answers will be welcomed

Answer (score 1):

`1 -` `how to hide the drupal information from my site ?`

- Remove the credits block.
- Use template files, so that the look and feel is different from default Drupal sites.
- Optimise your jss and css, so that it is difficult to identify that it is from Drupal.
- Remove changelog.txt file from root.

`2 -` `how to make the drupal site more secure ?`

- Have the latest stable version of Drupal and keep all your modules upto date. (Regularly check for security patches if there are no updates)
- Install [security review](http://drupal.org/project/security_review) module
- Theme is the weakest link in Drupal security. While theming make sure that you follow all the Drupal standards. Remember to sanitize data and use Drupal functions wherever possible.

`3 -` `how to make my site work as fast as possible when there is a lot of visitors and users on the site and there is a lot of interaction with the database at the same time?`

- [Memcache](http://drupal.org/project/memcache) : high-performance, distributed memory object caching system. Eases the load on DB
- Intelligent use of cache API in your custom modules.

`4 -` `how to configure drupal to work with high server load and how to configure my server's hardware to work with high load ?`

- [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) : Content delivery Network, use this if you are rich enough.
- [Press Flow](http://pressflow.org/) : Out of box performance for your Drupal site, from Four Kitchens.
- [Varnish](http://varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VarnishAndDrupal) : Reverse Proxy Cache

Answer (score 1):

Try using Pantheons hosting service at: http://getpantheon.com/
We are using it, and are very happy with it so far.

Answer (score 0):

1: Don't bother.

2: Make sure you keep your Drupal installation (including third-party modules) up to date.

3 and 4: Caching is a good step to take. Drupal comes with some handy caching features built-in (in the Performance settings), and modules like [CacheRouter](http://drupal.org/project/cacherouter) and [Boost](http://drupal.org/project/boost) take you a long way further.

Answer (score 0):

1 - What information exactly do you want to hide?

3 - Use the Devel modules to see what's happening. There's a lot of tweaking invovled here, especially if your using Views.

4 - Cache modules such as boost do a lot. Then there are things such as the web server, Nginx for example is generally faster then Apache, especially serving static content (and PHP-FPM for dynamic). You should also check out Memcached, APC or another php cache and of course Varnish cache is pretty awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I saw above you mentioning making Drupal working with more than one databases. If you mean replications, I think that's directly covered in Pressflow's introduction [here](http://fourkitchens.com/pressflow-makes-drupal-scale).